# How can I get the same currency selector as found on the Bills and Adjustments screen?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I'm adding a user field to the Task screen called UsrCuryId, similar to the CuryID field on the Bills and Adjustments screen:

[image]

I've modified the ASPX to include the following (taken from the Bills and Adjustments screen):

```
 <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Visible="False" Name="CurrencyView" />
 <pxa:PXCurrencyRate ID="edUsrCury" DataField="UsrCuryID" runat="server" RateTypeView="currencyinfo" DataMember="_Currency_" DataSourceID="ds"/>
```

And I've added the view for the 'RateTypeView' as follows in my Graph extension code:

```
public PXSelect<CurrencyInfo,
       Where<CurrencyInfo.curyInfoID, Equal<Current<CRActivity.UsrCuryInfoID>>>>currencyinfo;
```

This does NOT result in the same control style as seen on the Bills and Adjustments screen:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  What needs to be added?
Thanks...

Comment: I am not sure if it cause the problem or not, but APInvoice.curyInfoID looks a little bit suspicious in your PXSelect.

Comment: Yeah - you're right.  I fixed that, but still the same result.  I even added a UsrCuryInfoID (int64), along with a UsrCuryID (nvarchar(5))  same as in Bills and Adjustments.  Same result.